# C++: How to pass parameters to custom exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception

I have created a custom exception:

```
class MyIOException : public std::exception
{
public:
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "IO Exception";
  } 
};
```

and

```
class MyEmptyImageException : public MyIOException
{
private:
  std::string m_bucketName;
  std::string m_objectName;

public:

  MyEmptyImageException(const std::string& bn, const std::string& on) : m_bucketName(bn), m_objectName(on) {}
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    std::string msg = "Empty Image : " + m_bucketName + m_objectName;
    return msg.c_str();
  }  
};
```

And I try it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  try
  {
    // ... read image
    if (image.empty)
    {
      throw MyEmptyImageException(folderName, imageName);
    }
    // ... remained code
  }
  catch (MyEmptyImageException& meie)
  {
    std::cout << meie.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if I have done it right, could you correct me, or suggest a better implementation, because I am a beginner in using derived exceptions?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Note that your `throw()` specification in the second case is a lie. You may throw [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The person just wants to know how to pass parameters to the exception

Comment: @Nav, `throw MyEmptyImageException(folderName, imageName);` - Seems like they are and it compiles, but they're unsure whether the code is correct.

Comment: Ye, I have added the question, I am not sure if it is correct. Is it another better way to do it?

Comment: Downvoters willing to remove the downvotes? The OP corrected the reason you gave downvotes for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have correctly passed the parameters to the constructor of your exception class.

**But**, the function `MyEmptyImageException::what()` is incorrect because it returns `msg.c_str()`, where `msg` is allocated on the stack. When the function `what()` returns, them `msg` object is destroyed, and the `char*` pointer points to the buffer managed by a deallocated object. To fix that, you can construct the message in the constructor of `MyEmptyImageException` itself:

```
class MyEmptyImageException : public MyIOException
{
  std::string m_msg;
public:

  MyEmptyImageException(const std::string& bn, const std::string& on)
    : m_msg(std::string("Empty Image : ") + bn + on)
  {}

  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return m_msg.c_str();
  }
};
```

Comment: Nope, code isn't right. Undefined behavior in `MyEmptyImageException::what()`. He's returning a pointer to a temporary buffer (the one managed by `std::string msg`).

Comment: @Praetorian Oups! You are right. I have modified the answer.

Comment: A better solution than just making `msg` a member variable would be to construct the final message in the constructor itself. `MyEmptyImageException(const std::string& bn, const std::string& on) : m_msg("Empty Image : " + bn + on) {}`. This allows you to get rid of the other two, and now the `throw()` guarantee by `what()` is real.

Comment: @Praetorian: I suggest you write your own answer. I could modify mine using your suggestion, but I would prefer to upvote an answer of yours.

Comment: No, go ahead and update yours. I haven't written an answer yet because the question is probably a better fit for CodeReview.SE

Comment: @Praetorian: I have not found a way to suggest a move of the question to CodeReview. I have seen only a limited set of SE sites, in the user interface. All right, I will modify the answer.

Comment: I will go to CodeReview, I have not known it before